# In Perl, what is the easiest way to turn X seconds into format HH:MM:SS?

Tags: perl

In Perl, what is the easiest way to turn say `600 seconds` (ten minutes in notation `N` seconds) into `00:10:00` (ten minutes in notation `HH:MM:SS`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on your definition of "easiest".  I like reasonably future-proof code that I'll never have to think about again, which would look like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.10.0;

use DateTime::Duration;
use DateTime::Format::Duration;

sub duration_to_hms {
    my ($duration) = @_;

    my $formatter = DateTime::Format::Duration->new(
        pattern     => "%H:%M:%S",
        normalize   => 1,
    );

    return $formatter->format_duration($duration);
}

my $duration = DateTime::Duration->new(seconds => 600);

say duration_to_hms($duration);
```

Answer (score 8):

Use [gmtime](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/gmtime.html):

```
$seconds = 600;
printf ("%02d:%02d:%02d\n",(gmtime($seconds))[2,1,0]);
```

prints:

```
00:10:00
```

Comment: Oh, but do use [strftime](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/strftime.html). Then you don't have to slice the `tm` yourself. In Perl, we find it in the [POSIX module](http://perldoc.perl.org/POSIX.html). `say strftime "%T", gmtime $seconds`

Answer (score 1):

Use the POSIX function [**`strftime()`**](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/strftime.html).  Here is a full working example below...

```
use POSIX 'strftime';
my $seconds = 615;
print(strftime('%T', gmtime $seconds));
```

Example output from above would be:

> `00:10:15`

**NOTE**: This will not work if the hour values goes over `24`.  In that case, or if you just have a limitation on using POSIX tools, you can use this custom function to replace it...

```
sub formatSeconds {
        my ($args) = @_;

        my $seconds = $args->{seconds};

        my ($hours, $hourremainder) = (($seconds/(60*60)), $seconds % (60*60));
        my ($minutes, $seconds) = (int $hourremainder / 60, $hourremainder % 60);

        ($hours, $minutes, $seconds) = (sprintf("%02d", $hours), sprintf("%02d", $minutes), sprintf("%02d", $seconds));

        return $hours . ':' . $minutes . ':' . $seconds;
}

formatSeconds({seconds=>642});  // output: "00:10:42"
```

Thanks to @oylenshpeegul for the inspiration to use strftime!